# Display pdf file from oracle database (pdf path is stored in database) using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, pdf, handler

C# code:

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Pdfhandler.ashx?empid=" + TextBox8.Text;
```

Pdfhandler.ashx code:

```
{

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        string sql = "SELECT pdfpath FROM pdfstore WHERE empl_code = " + id + "";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        connection.Open();

        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            //byte[] file = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("imgpath");
            //byte[] file = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("imgpath");
            //Get Image Data
            //byte[] file = (byte[])reader["imgpath"];
            byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(reader["pdfpath"].ToString());

            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
            memoryStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(file);
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {

        }
```

When i run the code i can able to display the pdf for one employee by entering the employee code but if i enter another employee code in textbox , pdf for tat particular employee is not being displayed. Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: If pdfpath is just a string why use  ReadAllBytes?

Comment: Then what should I use instead?

Comment: Is there any problem with memorystream? Should i clear it? If so how? As i can able to display the pdf after sometime.

Comment: It is not clear if in the pdfpath is stored the NAME AND PATH of the pdf file or are stored the bytes used to rebuild the PDF

Comment: pdfpath just stores the current path where the pdf is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.TransmitFile(reader["pdfpath"].ToString()); //the path must be actual physical path of the file
    contest.Response.End();
}
else
{
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("No file found");
    contest.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working fine. But in internet explorer i need to refresh the page for the pdf to be opened. How to solve this issue?

Comment: You could try setting `HyperLink1.Target = "_blank";`. This would open the pdf in a new tab. then you will not need to refresh.

Comment: I have given this already. But still the issue is there, in firefox its working fine.